# Duplicate commits after rebase have been merged into the develop branch

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

I recently pulled down a remote branch that another developer was working on, let's call it `feature`. I then made the mistake of doing a rebase onto `develop` - the main working branch - which I've now come to know is something that you shouldn't do. The `feature` branch has since been merged into `develop`.

The problem I have now is that `develop` has a strange Git history. All of the commits from `feature` seem to be duplicated, they appear twice. However, they have different commit IDs.

My history looks a bit like this now (IDs are for demo purposes):

```
0007 commit from feature #3  <--- these commits are duplicated
0006 commit from feature #2
0005 commit from feature #1
0004 different commit from another branch #2
0004 different commit from another branch #1
0002 commit from feature #3
0002 commit from feature #2
0001 commit from feature #1
```

I've made a silly mistake! Is there anything I can do about this? The history looks ugly, but all the correct code seems to be there. Can I remove the duplicated commits? Or is there any other way to clean up the history?

Please write your answer for a less experienced Git user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### What happened

"Copy commits" is just what `git rebase` *does*. It copies some commits, then shuffles the branch pointers around so as to "forget" or "abandon" the original commits.  (But see below.)

Here is an illustration of how `git rebase` does this copying.  The single letters represent commits, and the names on the right are *branch names*, which actually point only to *one* commit, namely the "tip of the branch".  Each commit points back to its parent commit, i.e., the `A--B` connector lines are really meant to be left-pointing arrows (and ones that go diagonally also still point left, to earlier commits, with later commits being towards the right):

```
     C--D   <-- branch1
    /
A--B
    \
     E      <-- branch2
```

This is the "before" picture, where you have only "original" commits.  You now decide to `git checkout branch1` and `git rebase branch2` so that `C` and `D` come *after* `E`.  But Git can't actually *change* the original `C--D` at all, so instead it *copies* them to new copies, `C'` and `D'`, with the new ones being slightly different: they come after `E` (and also use whatever code changes you did in `E`):

```
     C--D      [abandoned]
    /
A--B
    \
     E         <-- branch2
      \
       C'-D'   <-- branch1
```

Completely forgetting the original `C--D` would be OK here, but what if you decide this was a bad idea after all?  A rebase keeps the original value of the branch in your "reflogs" to remember it.  It also uses the special name `ORIG_HEAD`.  This is much easier to use, but there's only *one* `ORIG_HEAD`, while there are a potentially-infinite number of reflog entries.  Reflog entries are kept for at least 30 days by default, giving you time to change your mind.  Look back up at the second graph and imagine that `ORIG_HEAD` is added.

Now, the problem you have hit occurs because it's not *just* branch names that remember previous commits.  Each commit *also* remembers *its own* previous commits, via those connecting, left-pointing arrows.  So let's see what happens if there was either another name, or some other (merge) commit, remembering `C` and `D`.  For instance, what if we have this much more complicated starting graph:

```
    .-----F    <-- branch3
   /     /
  /  C--D      <-- branch1
 /  /
A--B
    \
     E         <-- branch2
```

If we now "rebase" `branch1`, we get this:

```
    .-----F    <-- branch3
   /     /
  /  C--D      [ORIG_HEAD and reflog]
 /  /
A--B
    \
     E         <-- branch2
      \
       C'-D'   <-- branch1
```

Commit `F` is a *merge commit*: it points back to both commit `A` *and* commit `D`.  So it retains the original `D`, which retains the original `C`, giving us kind of a mess.

`F` could be a plain ordinary commit, pointing back only to `D`, and we would see the same problem.  Plain ordinary commits are much easier to copy, though, so if `F` were *not* a merge—if our `F` pointed back only to `D` and not to `A`—we could carefully rebase `branch3` as well, copying `F` to `F'`, where `F'` comes after our new `D'`.  It's possible to re-do the merge too, but that's a bit trickier (not that copying `F` correctly is all that easy either way—it's easy to "get lost" and copy `C--D` *yet again* by mistake).

#### When this happens

You will encounter this problem whenever you copy commits that you or someone else made, *and* both you and the "someone else" (perhaps the "other you") are also *still using* the originals.  This happened with our commit `F`, for instance: we were still using the original `C--D` chain.  We can fix this by making a new `F'` and using that, *as long as* we're the only one using `branch3`.  But if `branch3` is *published*, or for that matter if we've published `branch1`, so that someone else might have them as `origin/branch1` or `origin/branch3`, we have lost control over the original copies of `C--D`.

Hence the standard advice is to rebase only *private* (unpublished) commits, since you know who is using them—it's just you of course—and you can check with yourself and make sure you're not using them, or that it's OK to copy them because you also plan to copy or otherwise re-do commits like `F`.

If you have done the rebase—made the copies—*and* published them (pushed them to `origin`), you're kind of stuck.  You can "undo" your rebase anyway, and beg everyone else who shares the use of `origin` to make sure *they* don't use your `C'-D'` type copies for anything because you're putting the originals back.

(For more-advanced groups of users, you can even all agree that certain branches get rebased regularly, and you and they must all recognize when this happens, and *all* of you will then take care to switch to the new commit copies.  However, this is probably not what you want to do right now!)

#### Undoing it

So, if you (a) *can* and (b) *want to* "undo" your rebase, now the reflog, or the saved `ORIG_HEAD`, really come in handy.  Let's take the second example again and look at what we have after we forgot that `branch3` still remembers the original `C-D` commits:

```
    .-----F    <-- branch3
   /     /
  /  C--D      [ORIG_HEAD and reflog]
 /  /
A--B
    \
     E         <-- branch2
      \
       C'-D'   <-- branch1
```

Now, imagine we erase the name `branch1` from the bottom row and write in a new `<-- branch1` pointing to commit `D`:

```
    .-----F    <-- branch3
   /     /
  /  C--D      <-- branch1
 /  /
A--B
    \
     E         <-- branch2
      \
       C'-D'   [abandoned]
```

Now that we've abandoned `C'-D'`, just stop looking at it.  Compare this graph to the original graph, and voila!  That's what you want!

The command that "moves" a branch label in arbitrary fashion like this is `git reset` (it moves the *current* branch, so you have to be on `branch1`).  Look up the raw commit hash for `D` in the reflog, or check that `ORIG_HEAD` is correct, or use the reflog spelling to identify commit `D`.  (For newbies, I find cut-and-paste of the raw hash is the way to go.)  For instance, try:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline ORIG_HEAD
```

to see if `ORIG_HEAD` gets you the right hash.  If not, try `git reflog branch1` (looking at the specific reflog for `branch1` here) to find hashes, then use:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline branch1@{1}
```

(or cut and paste the raw hash instead of using `branch1@{1}`).  Once you've found the desired "original" commit, you can then:

```
$ git status     # to make sure you're on the right branch
                 # and that everything is clean, because
                 # "git reset --hard" wipes out in-progress work!
$ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

(or put in `branch1@{1}`, or the raw hash ID, in place of `ORIG_HEAD` as usual).<sup>1</sup>  That moves the current branch (which we just checked) so that it points to the given commit (`branch1@{1}`, from the reflog, or `ORIG_HEAD` or a raw hash ID), to get us that final graph drawing back.  The `--hard` sets both our index/staging-area, and our work-tree, to match the new commit to which we've just re-pointed our branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>The general idea here, which recurs all the time in Git, is that we must *name some specific commit*, from which Git finds the *rest* of the commits if necessary.  Any name works: a branch name, a name like `HEAD`, a reflog name like `master@{1}`, or a raw commit hash ID.  Git does not really care *how* you tell it "look at this here commit"; ultimately, Git resolves that name to one those big ugly SHA-1 hash IDs, and uses that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `git reflog` to revert your changes.

Read all about it in **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716)** (how to recover previous head/ how to undo changes):

***What to do?***

Type `git reflog` and find out the "last good" sha-1 which you want to go back to.
run

```
git reset <SHA-1> --hard
```

And you are back in the previous commit before you did your mistake.

Comment: Should I do this on `develop` or `feature`, or another branch entirely?

Comment: `reflog` is per repo so in case you want to revert specific branch switch to teh desired branch that you wish to fix